# Is it possible to discover other smart tv's with a Roku TV?

Tags: udp, roku, brightscript, smart-tv, ssdp

I am a newbie to Roku development. I want to find out whether the Roku TV discovers all the other TVs(Samsung, LG, Android & Apple TVs). If yes, please give me the function to discover the other TVs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Roku by itself does not do discovery for other devices. If you have something specific in mind though, you should be able to send and listen for UDP, see https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roDataGramSocket

Answer (score 0):

I used the function in this link https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roDataGramSocket and used address as 239.255.255.250 and port - 1900 which is used for SSDP( simple service discovery protocol).
I was able to see the other smart TV's such as Samsung and Sony Bravia in my console log.

Comment: No, it clearly tells that **you** used SSDP to discover other devices. :) Or that Roku app *can* use HTTPU/UPnP, like you did. What makes you say that Roku discovers other devices SSDP?! You might be thinking about CEC which is HDMI affair (go Settings > System > Control other devices)

Comment: Well, yes I used SSDP to discover other devices on network from Roku application. Roku does not use it.